# A lot of MXML components in Flex project

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I develop a small application with news and list of charging stations in my country. But I`m a beginner in programming, so... When user click Charging Station button on HomeView, views is pushed on RegionView (here is a 7 MXML sub-files), then user select Region and view is pushed on list of charging station in this region. And here is a 10+ MXML sub-components, each for one charging station, because when user click on Charging station, view is pushed on DetailsViewOfCH (unique details for each one).

My question: is this metod good or will application is too big?![enter image description here][1]

Here is a illustration

http:// shrani.si/f/2k/Qc/2fOE4oro/untitled-1.jpg

Short explain: one HomeView MXML -> Region MXML (7 MXML components, each for one region) -> Charge Station MXML (10+ MXML components for one region) -> I have a 60 charging station, so 60 MXML components files for details of charging station.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you talking about each mxml being a new View?

Comment: yes, i use each mxml for each detailsView of Charging station. I post code below.

Answer (score 0):

How does your application perform on a real Android device?

Is navigation between the views slow? There's [some good reading](http://polygeek.com/4774_air-mobile_performance-tip-using-flex) on this. I've also heard of people waiting until after `viewActivated` is dispatched to add the "more expensive" view components to the `View` class, to speed up the transition.

Also, you should be using a [`List`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) component and a `LabelItemRenderer` or `IconItemRender` on the screen that displays the list of 60 charging stations. The Flex `List` component only creates as many item renderers that are needed to display what is on screen. When you scroll the list, it repopulates the item renderers with new data from the list. If you are already using this, stop worrying :)

Note that the label/icon item renderers are optimized for mobile apps.

- [CheckBox in List using MobileIconItemRenderer for Flex Mobile](http://www.flex-blog.com/checkbox-in-list-using-mobileiconitemrenderer-for-flex-mobile/)
- [Building a mobile employee directory sample with Flex and Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/employee-directory-android-flex.html)
- [Example from `IconItemRenderer` documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IconItemRenderer.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Answer (score 0):

I hear what you're saying about having too many views - Try something like the following:

Make ONE mxml for Home, ONE for Region, ONE for Charge Station and ONE for Components. Everywhere you have hard-coded data, replace with variables. Then, all of the data you have on all of those 50+ mxml files you can put into a data model of some sort - sqlite, xml, localstore, etc.

Write a class to access the data, and then you can pass the reference, populated with your data, to each of the 4 views. So every time a selection is made in each view, it narrows the data to a more specific location as required.

[Passing Data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html#WSe11993ea1bd776e577ad4b2d12a42c5858a-7fff)

[Passing More Data with extra code help](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Passing_data_between_Views-18854.html)

[Accessing Data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5f39f-7ff7.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5f39f-7fef)

[More about a data model](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b51.html)

[Here are your local data storage options](http://blog.crankybit.com/notes-adobe-air-local-data-storage-options/)

[And here you'll find help with getting started](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/documentation.html)

Hopefully that will get you on the right path.